# Why is the mRNA not damaged at -70 C temperature Corona vaccine?

Tags: mrna

Why is the mRNA not damaged at -70 C temperature Corona vaccine?

[Need for -70 degree temperature for Corona vaccine](https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/96799/need-for-70-degree-temperature-for-corona-vaccine)

I assume that if I, for example, were to freeze, say, a chicken egg after heating to room temperature, the protein binding would be destroyed.

What mechanism, process or substance ensures that at -70 C mRNA is not damaged? Or is this a natural property of the mRNA itself?

As I understand it, random errors in the conformation of DNA, RNA and proteins often lead to information distortion.

https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&u=https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konformacja

Sorry for My English.

Comment: An egg is an egg. A molecule is a molecule. If you ask this sort of question you need to set out a chemical reason why a molecule should be harmed by freezing. Do you have one?

Comment: Yes I have one: https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=pl&tl=en&u=https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Konformacja

Auto translated from polish.

Comment: Maybe you want to ask here or chem SE a simple q like "how do cryoprotectants work for preserving RNA?" instead of offering your theories. Conformational isomerism (which you've linked to in Polish) doesn't seem to have anything to do with that... (I should also say here that the vaccine is not just mRNA, but mRNA contained in lipid nano-particles [LNPs], so some of the freeze-thaw effects on cell-like structures may matter too. But as far as I can tell cryoprotectants are used even for "unwrapped" RNA preservation, so you may start with asking about that.)

Answer (score 1):

> Why is the mRNA not damaged at -70 C temperature Corona vaccine?

Actually they use Sucrose as cryoprotectant.

https://medicalsciences.stackexchange.com/questions/25289/why-use-sucrose-rather-than-glucose-in-an-injectable-vaccine/25290